# iOS Simulator Safari not opening facebook

Tags: ios, mobile-safari

Safari ios simulator having error. "Safari cannot open the page because it could not establish a secure connection to the server". It can't open facebook or twitter. Some other sites are okay. Anyone know how to fix it?

P.S. Badly need to fix this and able to open my browser on simulator. I have facebook and google for authentication and I need it to work.

P.P.S Using just the regular safari on mac works just fine. Only the safari on simulator.

Comment: Sounds like your network is compromised at some point, interfering with the certificate chain of those two domains. Can you open the sites on your regular browser on the mac?

Comment: https://appuals.com/safari-cant-establish-a-secure-connection-to-the-server/

Comment: are you sure your url of facebook contains "https"?

Comment: Yes, I am using https. Facebook and twitter have this error. Youtube is fine.

Comment: @luk2302 Using normal browser on safari on mac is just fine. No problem with safar browsing anything. Only the ios simulator.

Comment: Did you find the solution for this issue?

Comment: Any Solution???